# STM32L010RB как правильно использовать ADC несколько каналлов одноверменно

Tags: c, stm32

Помогите пожалуйста советом. Бьюсь несколько дней с опцией ADC.

Я использую двухканальный АЦП IN0 и IN1 на микроконтроллере STM32L010RB через библиотеку HAL.

Если проверять по отдельности, все в порядке, но когда я проверяю вместе, у меня все время одна и та же проблема: первый канал перезаписывает данные на втором канале, и у меня те же данные на IN0 и IN1 в терминале

Функция для выбора IN0.

```
void ADC_Select_CH0(void)
{
    ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig_0 = {0};

    sConfig_0.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_0;
    sConfig_0.Rank = 0;
      if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc, &sConfig_0) != HAL_OK)
      {
        Error_Handler();
      }
}
```

Функция для выбора IN1

```
void ADC_Select_CH1(void)
{
    ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig_1 = {0};

    sConfig_1.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_1;
    sConfig_1.Rank = 1;
      if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc, &sConfig_1) != HAL_OK)
      {
        Error_Handler();
      }
}
```

основной цикл

```
while(1)
{
  ADC_Select_CH0();
    HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc);
    HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc, 100);
  Axis[0] = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc);
    HAL_ADC_Stop(&hadc);

  ADC_Select_CH1();
    HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc);
    HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc, 100);
  Axis[1] = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc);
    HAL_ADC_Stop(&hadc);

  sprintf(Tx_Data, "Axis X: %d;\r\nAxis Y: %d;\r\n\n\n", Axis[0], Axis[1]);
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t*)Tx_Data, strlen(Tx_Data), 1000);
}
```

ADC конфигурация:

```
static void MX_ADC_Init(void)
{
  hadc.Instance = ADC1;
  hadc.Init.OversamplingMode = DISABLE;
  hadc.Init.ClockPrescaler = ADC_CLOCK_SYNC_PCLK_DIV2;
  hadc.Init.Resolution = ADC_RESOLUTION_12B;
  hadc.Init.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_160CYCLES_5;
  hadc.Init.ScanConvMode = ADC_SCAN_DIRECTION_FORWARD;
  hadc.Init.DataAlign = ADC_DATAALIGN_RIGHT;
  hadc.Init.ContinuousConvMode = ENABLE;
  hadc.Init.DiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc.Init.ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONVEDGE_NONE;
  hadc.Init.ExternalTrigConv = ADC_SOFTWARE_START;
  hadc.Init.DMAContinuousRequests = DISABLE;
  hadc.Init.EOCSelection = ADC_EOC_SINGLE_CONV;
  hadc.Init.Overrun = ADC_OVR_DATA_PRESERVED;
  hadc.Init.LowPowerAutoWait = DISABLE;
  hadc.Init.LowPowerFrequencyMode = DISABLE;
  hadc.Init.LowPowerAutoPowerOff = DISABLE;
  if (HAL_ADC_Init(&hadc) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}
```

Comment: Если нужно все каналы сразу опрашивать, то скорее всего без DMA не обойтись.

Comment: Не все, только два. Знаю про метод с DMA но хотел бы разобраться почему не работает без DMA

Comment: [Тут](https://istarik.ru/blog/stm32/113.html) довольно подробно описано про ADC, может что вычитаете.

Comment: У вас упоминается ScanConvMode и ContinuousMode. Попробуйте их отключить, вам нужен режим однократного преобразования.

Comment: Всем спасибо, нашел решение в этом режиме. После каждого вызова функции нужно менять ранг на `sConfig.Rank = ADC_RANK_NONE;` и в моем случае в моем контролере нет возможности менять последовательность измернений между каналами, только один за одним т.е IN0, IN1, IN2.... и так далее поетому номер ранга всегда соответствует номеру канала. 
`sConfig.Rank = ADC_RANK_CHANNEL_NUMBER;`